# How to find all ActiveRecord objects which have for a many_to_many attribute a collection that contains all associated objects with specified array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 ActiveRecord objects associated with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship: Article and Tag.

I would like to select all Articles with both tags with name foo and bar.

I'm trying to get the following statement to go, but no luck.  Any help appreciated.

```
# gives me non-inclusive associated articles.
Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: ['foo','bar']})
```

EDIT: pseudo code to further explain:

```
article_one.tags = ['foo', 'bar']  # want this one only

article_two.tags = ['foo', 'baz']  # no good

article_three.tags = ['bar', 'baz']  # no good
```

The statement above gives me all three :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `group`, like this:

```
Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: %w(foo bar)}).group('articles.id').having('count(*) = ?', 2)
```

If you use `join` and if there are more than one `tags` with name `foo` or `bar` attached to specific article, there will be two rows with this article in results. So you just have to group your results by `article id` (or any other unique key, but primary key is most convenient here) and return only the ones with count equal to `2` (i.e. with both of your tags attached).

Comment: yeah, i need to go to bed soon...  thank you for fixing my formatting!!

Comment: wouldn't this give me all the articles that only contain either foo or bar as well?  I want to return results that include both

Comment: @believesInSanta right, I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Would you care to explain what you're doing with group and having methods?  thx.

Comment: @believesInSanta I added some explanation. If there is still something unclear, ask.

Comment: I see now.  The logic got me confused for a second.  You are essentially returning more items than you need and then removing the ones whose occurrence count is not equal to the array count.  I was thinking more in terms of a 'CONTAIN' or 'LIKE' SQL statement... I don't know if ActiveRecord has those implemented or not.